# How do I read a property from my main form in a user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have written a user control, MenuItem, which inherits from a Form Label.

I have a backgroundworker thread whose IsBusy property is exposed through a property in the MainForm as IsBackgroundBusy.

How do I read this property from the MenuItem usercontrol? I am currently using Application.UseWaitCursor and I set that in the backgroundworker and it works perfectly, however I do not want the cursor to change. That's why I figured a property that I could set would be much better.

Here is the code in my MainForm:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public bool IsBackgroundBusy
    {
        get
        {
            return bwRefreshGalleries.IsBusy;
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for my usercontrol:

```
public partial class MenuItem: Label
{
    private bool _disableIfBusy = false;

    [Description("Change color if Application.UseWaitCursor is True")]
    public bool DisableIfBusy
    {
        get
        {
            return _disableIfBusy;
        }

        set
        {
            _disableIfBusy = value;
        }
    }

    public MenuItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter( EventArgs e )
    {
        if ( Application.UseWaitCursor && _disableIfBusy )
        {
            this.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
        }
        else
        {
            this.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        }

        base.OnMouseEnter( e );
    }
```

Comment: Is the heart of your question how to [access form from usercontrol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921354/access-form-from-usercontrol)?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is. I know I can use an event in the form instead but I wanted to avoid that if at all possible for the sake of simplicity when reusing the control since many menu items will be created.

Comment: @ryanyuyu That works as long as you don't mind locking the usercontrol to one type of form.  More complicated would be to create a form interface and have the forms that use the control inherit from that.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I'm sorry, I just realized there was a link in your comment. I tried doing that as well but I couldn't declare a form as MainForm within my usercontrol. I tried to set a reference to the project but I couldn't because it would cause a circular dependency.

Comment: Yeah, and since BackgroundWorkers were mentioned... that probably won't work too well.  Well that explains why this is a separate question now.

Comment: You can always create an interface which exposes the `IsBackgroundBusy { get; }` property which is implemented by your `MainForm` and used by your `MenuItem`. This way your `MainForm` isn't coupled with your `MenuItem`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: it's not clear to me whether you have an actual `UserControl` here or not. The `MenuItem` class you show inherits `Label`, not `UserControl`. You should probably avoid using the term "usercontrol" or "user control" when you are not actually dealing with a `UserControl` object).

Absent a complete code example, it's hard to know exactly what the right solution here is. However, assuming you are using the `BackgroundWorker` in a typical fashion, then you simply need for the owner of the control (i.e. the containing `Form`) to pass the necessary state to the control as it changes. E.g.:

```
class MenuItem : Label
{
    public bool IsParentBusy { get; set; }
}

// I.e. some method where you are handling the BackgroundWorker
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...some other initialization...

    bwRefreshGalleries.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender1, e1) =>
    {
        menuItem1.IsParentBusy = false;
    };

    menuItem1.ParentIsBusy = true;
    bwRefreshGalleries.RunAsync();
}
```

If you already have a handler for the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, then just put the statement to set the `IsParentBusy` property there instead of adding another handler.

Then instead of using the `Application.UseWaitCursor` property, you can just look at the `IsParentBusy` property.

There are other mechanisms you could use; I do agree with the general sentiment that the `MenuItem` control should not be tied to your specific `Form` sub-class. If for some reason the above doesn't work in your case, you need to elaborate on your question: provide a good code example and explain exactly why simply having the container of the control manage its state directly doesn't work for you

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the terminology I should use to properly describe my question and also for your answer. It accomplishes exactly what I want just in a different method which I didn't consider. However, I'm getting an error when setting (sender, e). Cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'sender'. But what you're pointing out is perfect if I can get it to work.

Comment: I was drowning in a puddle. I declared a 'new' sender and eventargs (s, i) and it works perfectly. Thank you @Peter!

Comment: Happy to help. Sorry for the typo...I will edit the post to fix that, in case someone else is looking for a similar solution. Glad you were able to figure out my mistake on your own. :)