# calling button click function from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

i currently have one form and a few user control, i have a panel set from the `Form1` - mainpanel, so that whenever i click a button, one of the user control will be showing on the mainPanel.

my problem is that one of the control(`InfoSetting`) has some other new buttons, and when i click it I would like the mainPanel to show the new user control. However, right now all other buttons from Form1 is working fine, but when I click on the `InfoSetting` button, nothing seems to show up.

here is my code from `Form1`

```
public partial class Form1 : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
{
    InfoSettings infoSetting;
    CashSales cashSales; 
    PriceSetting priceSetting; 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        infoSetting  = new InfoSettings();
        cashSales = new CashSales();
        priceSetting = new PriceSetting();
    }


    protected void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        buttonHandler(sender);
    }

    public void buttonHandler(object sender)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        mainPanel.Controls.Clear();

        if (button != null)
        {
            switch (button.Name)
            {
                case "HomeBtn":
                    infoSetting.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    mainPanel.Controls.Add(infoSetting);
                    break;

                case "cashSalesBtn":
                    cashSales.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    mainPanel.Controls.Add(cashSales);
                    break;

                case "settingBtn":
                    infoSetting.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    mainPanel.Controls.Add(infoSetting);
                    break;

                case "priceSettingBtn":
                    cashSales.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    mainPanel.Controls.Add(cashSales);
                    break;

                default:
                    mainPanel.Controls.Clear();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is the code from the `InfoSetting` user control

```
public partial class InfoSettings : UserControl
{


    public InfoSettings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void priceSettingBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.buttonHandler(sender);
    }
}
```

Comment: In `priceSettingBtn_Click` you're **creating a new form**

Comment: @stuartd the eventhandler is in form1 as well. In this case, what is the better way to resolve this problem? please and thank you

Comment: @stuartd sorry maybe i didn't explain it clearly.
both the ButtonClicked and buttonHandler are in Form1, and the priceSettingBtn_Click is in another userControl. i have edited the code to make it a bit more clear

Comment: See [access form from user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921354/access-form-from-usercontrol)

Comment: let me give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as [stuartd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43846/stuartd) said you can add a call to your parent Form:

```
public partial class InfoSettings : UserControl
{
    public InfoSettings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void settingBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = (Form1) this.Parent;
        form1.buttonHandler(sender);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to have a common class that you can access in both form and user control and have the code you want to run in a method there.  Something like:

```
    public class FormHelper
    {
        public void CodeIWantToRunIn2Places()
        {
           // Implementation Here
        }
    }
```

You can implement the above as a singleton so you have access in both places.  Then in your form classes you could do:

```
    FormHelper.Instance.CodeIWantToRunIn2Places();
```

In your event handler as well as in your user control.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the Form 1 as "static" and also the method **buttonHandler(object sender)** as "static" as well.

Then inside the **priceSettingBtn_Click**, call the below function directly

Form1.buttonHandler(sender);

Answer (score 0):

I would have a global object with a pointer to all the forms in the application.

```
public Global
{
     public Form1 MainForm;
     public Dialog1 D1;
...
}

public static Global = new Global();
```

In as each form is created

```
Global.MainForm = form1;
```

then you can go

```
private void priceSettingBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Global.MainForm.buttonHandler(sender);
}
```

As other have said , its probably better to not call the click handler, its better to have this code and the real click handler call a business logic level function