# Focus matching word in opened notepad with Process method in C#

Tags: c#, process, filesystems, notepad

I'm trying to do something like add the CTRL-F mechanism to my C# application in visual studio.

My app uses the Process.start method to open Windows Notepad and find a given word.   I want to find this word in Notepad and focus it.

I have a way to search this word but how to focus to the correct line as would  happen if the user clicked CTRL-F?

Does anybody know how to do this? Or maybe there is there a framework which can help?

My application is about searching any file by typing any sequence of string in textbox and getting file, which contains it, after that i have a open function of this file and i want to get focused word, which im typed in opened notepad (cuz i got txt file containing this string)

For example i typed "hello" in textbox and get file.txt and inside this after opened i have focused word "hello"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bring another processes Window to foreground when it has ShowInTaskbar = false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636721/bring-another-processes-window-to-foreground-when-it-has-showintaskbar-false)

Comment: It is not clear how your application interacts with Notepad.  Is there a Notepad API that allows you to script that application?  It sounds like maybe you are trying the script the Windows 10 UI to open and drive Notepad, is this true?  Or are you trying to build something that behaves like Notepad.  You need to be clearer.  Good luck and welcome!

Comment: My application is about searching any file by typing any sequence of string in textbox and getting file, which contains it, after that i have a open function of this file and i want to get focused word, which im typed in opened notepad (cuz i got txt file containing this string)

Comment: For example i typed "hello" in textbox and get file.txt and inside this after opened i have focused word "hello"

Answer (score 0):

Code to do this:

```cs
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("yourProcess");
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    SendKeys.Send("^(f)");
    foreach (char c in textBox1.Text)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{" + c + "}");
    }
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    //if you want to automatycally remove search window use:
    SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know also how to do "find" method after ctrl+f click?

Comment: Or you can use PreviewKeyDown event

Comment: So after trying set "SendKeys.Send("^{F}") in if(keybind) now i must do something with focus() method inside this method block? (Im thinking about how to handle and get final focused matching word)

Comment: I don't understand what are you going to do.

Comment: What do you exactly need? @SilverRaven655

Comment: Now I'm edited my question and additionally described problem

Comment: I tried your code but i had to change 'Send' to 'SendWait' cuz i got message: 'SendKeys cannot run inside this application because the application is not handling Windows messages.  Either change the application to handle messages, or use the SendKeys.SendWait method' , also i had problem with: "this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;" and i got error that my textbox control doesnt have this property. When i skip this line and also change: 'Send' to 'SendWait' i have no errors but focusing word doesnt work

Comment: Have you used this code in another class? @SilverRaven655

Comment: I have created User Control and then i used this code in its xaml.cs class

Comment: I added below code that i have for now with your suggestions

Comment: Which project type do you use?

Comment: I use WPF project type

Comment: and this is the problem :(

Comment: I must do by this form, but WindowState is so important to work this all code?

Comment: If no i have no idea why this not work :(

Comment: yes, because when notepad window shows it is not selected

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841258/minimize-a-window-in-wpf

Comment: Try this @SilverRaven655 :)

Comment: Do you know that its other option to select notepad window other than minimize window?

Comment: Im trying something do with code from your upper link but for now im getting only errors :/

Comment: Have you added usings?

Comment: Yes, all wchich were required

Comment: But i think that i must do something with main window and minimize this, but if i want to get access to it from my search control class i cant get window style option or any similar

Comment: make "public static YourFormName nameYouWant;" in form class and in public YourFormName "nameYouWant = this;" or something similar @SilverRaven655

Comment: and you can use nameYouWant in your textbox class

Comment: I did something like in my form class: "public static MainView mainview;" and: "public Mainview(){ InitializeComponent(); mainview=this;}" and in my textbox class i tried: "Mainview.mainview..." reference but i got error that: "Name type mainview doesnt exist in MainView type"

Comment: Try to use the Mainview instead of the MainView @SilverRaven655

Comment: MainView is my name of main window form, and i change it to: "public static MainView mainview;" and: "public MainView(){ InitializeComponent(); mainview=this;}" but still the same problem

Comment: Visual cant read property mainview which i wrote in MainView constructor

Comment: Can't you use one class?

Comment: Can't because i have two classes one is MainView form which contains main Window and User Control class, in which i have button click method to open a notepad according with upper code

Comment: I added also all usings

Comment: MainView is your form and class name?

Comment: Ahh no my fault

Comment: My code class for MainView is MainView.xaml.cs

Comment: So use your class name instead of form name

Comment: But MainView.xaml and MainView.xaml.cs is i guess the same object as MainView to reference

Comment: Now i tried and can't get other object than MainView in my control class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921354/access-form-from-usercontrol/17398854 try this

Comment: Still nothing, but i found a InputSimulator library for simulating keys shortcuts so maybe this will work for my project

Comment: But you have to minimize the window anyway

Comment: Yes, but option from link upper i think doesnt't work for wpf project

Comment: Maybe maximize window will help?

Comment: No, you can also deselect window, but I think you can't do that by code

Comment: There is no chance for deselect?

Comment: This is almost the same as Minimize

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for now (but not working) inside: "private async void OpeningFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)"

```
        try
        {
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

            startInfo.FileName = PathResult.ToString();
            startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + PathResult.ToString() + "\"";
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

            Process.Start(startInfo);
       
            MessageBox.Show(ControlHelper.WordToFind);
           
            await Task.Delay(1000);

           
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^(f)");

            foreach(char x in ControlHelper.WordToFind)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{" + x + "}");
            }

            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
            
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + PathResult.ToString());
        }
```